# Can a “negative degree” line bundle on a reducible curve have global section?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Suppose $A,B$ are curves on smooth projective surface, having no common components and intersect, so $(A.B)>0$,do we have $H^0(O_A(-B|_A))=0?$ (here $A,B$ are effective divisors, may be irreduced and reducible)

If $A$ is irreducible it is right since any regular section associates to a divisor of positive degree, and the degree is preserved by linear equivalence. But in this case it seemes not to be the concept of linear equivalence preserves degree.

I think there may be counter examples although it seems right.

Comment: If $A$ has a connected component which doesn't touch $B$, the bundle will have a nonzero global section. If it doesn't, then the global sections must be zero (at least if $A$ is reduced).

Comment: So does it mean if $A$ is reduced and each component meets $B$, then $H^0(A,O(-B))=0$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (Each _connected_ component, to be clear.)

Comment: Thanks! Is there counterexample for $B$ meets each component of $A$, but $A$ is not reduced?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Say $A$ has two components $A_1$ and $A_2$, meeting in a point, and $A_2$ has a double structure. Suppose $B$ meets $A_1$ but not $A_2$. Then $-B_{|A}$ has a global section which is $0$ on $A_1$, and equals a nonzero linear polynomial on $A_2$ with a zero at the point $A_1 \cap A_2$.